# Swift - Navigation Bar with background image and ContentView with rounded corners

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to develop an app with a custom navigation bar like the one in the following image:

[image]

I think that I need to create a custom navigation bar that has a background image without a shadow below it. But I don't know how to add rounded corners to the top of the contentView.
Can you please give me some advice on what I should do, and links to any kind of documentation would be awesome!